# Displaying selected child node from url

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a JSON type data source that has the following structure:

```
{
    "list":
    [
        {
            "id": "4167845External",
            "personId": 4167845,
            "profileId": 4268472,
            "personType": "External",
            "cat": "person",
            "imageId": "10300600",
            "extn": "88976",
            "profileUrl":
            [
                "id-mark",
                "mar123"
            ]}],
```

For the array `profileUrl`, I wrote the following JavaScript code to get it display on the web page:

```
function Staff(person) {
    var list = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < person.length; ++i) {
        var record = person[i];
        list += 
            "<tr><td>" 
            + record.profileUrl 
            + "</td><tr>\n";
    }
    document.getElementById("showList").innerHTML = list;
}
```

and the page will display `id-mark,mar123` as I run it, but what should I do if I want to display `mar123` only ?

Comment: Ask for the second element of the array,  eg.  record.profileUrl[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`profileUrl` is an array so you must access the property as if it was an array, e.g., `record.profileUrl[1]`:

```
function Staff(person) {
    var list = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < person.length; ++i) {
        var record = person[i];
        list += 
            "<tr><td>" 
            + record.profileUrl[1] 
            + "</td><tr>\n";
    }
    document.getElementById("showList").innerHTML = list;
}
```

An array in JavaScript is defined like this:

```
var myVar = [ "id-mark", "id-mark" ];
```

Each element can be accessed like this:

```
console.log( myVar[0] ); // outputs: id-mark
console.log( myVar[1] ); // outputs: mar123
```

or, can be looped through like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<myVar.length; i++) {
    console.log(myVar[i]);
}
```